# cannot add node group to aws eks using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I have this main.tf terraform file:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "ca-central-1"
    access_key = "***"
    secret_key = "***"
}

resource "aws_iam_account_alias" "alias" {
  account_alias = "***"
}


resource "aws_budgets_budget" "eks" {
  name              = "aws-eks"
  budget_type       = "COST"
  limit_amount      = "30"
  limit_unit        = "USD"
  time_period_end   = "2087-06-15_00:00"
  time_period_start = "2017-07-01_00:00"
  time_unit         = "MONTHLY"

  notification {
    comparison_operator        = "GREATER_THAN"
    threshold                  = 80
    threshold_type             = "PERCENTAGE"
    notification_type          = "FORECASTED"
    subscriber_email_addresses = ["amin.bamavadat@gmail.com"]
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

variable "public_subnet_cidrs" {
 type        = list(string)
 description = "Public Subnet CIDR values"
 default     = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
}
variable "private_subnet_cidrs" {
 type        = list(string)
 description = "Private Subnet CIDR values"
 default     = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
}

variable "azs" {
 type        = list(string)
 description = "Availability Zones"
 default     = ["ca-central-1a", "ca-central-1b", "ca-central-1d"]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
 count      = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
 vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
 cidr_block = element(var.public_subnet_cidrs, count.index)
 availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
 tags = {
   Name = "Public Subnet ${count.index + 1}"
 }
}
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
 count      = length(var.private_subnet_cidrs)
 vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
 cidr_block = element(var.private_subnet_cidrs, count.index)
 availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
 tags = {
   Name = "Private Subnet ${count.index + 1}"
 }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
 tags = {
   Name = "main VPC IG"
 }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "second_rt" {
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
 route {
   cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
   gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
 }
 tags = {
   Name = "2nd Route Table"
 }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_subnet_asso" {
 count = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
 subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.public_subnets[*].id, count.index)
 route_table_id = aws_route_table.second_rt.id
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eks_assume_role_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["eks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks-iam-role" {
 name = "eks-iam-role"
 path = "/"
 assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eks_assume_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eks_workerodes_assume_role_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks-workernodes-iam-role" {
 name = "eks-workernodes-iam-role"
 path = "/"
 assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eks_workerodes_assume_role_policy.json
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
 policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
 role    = aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly-EKS" {
 policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
 role    = aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
role    = aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
role    = aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds" {
policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds"
role    = aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
role    = aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role.name
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks-cluster" {
 name = "eks-cluster"
 role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role.arn

 vpc_config {
  subnet_ids = [ for subnet in aws_subnet.private_subnets: subnet.id ]
 }

 depends_on = [
  aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role
 ]
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group" {
  cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster.name
  node_group_name = "workernodes"
  node_role_arn  = aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role.arn
  subnet_ids   = [ for subnet in aws_subnet.private_subnets: subnet.id ]
  instance_types = ["t3.small"]
 
  scaling_config {
   desired_size = 1
   max_size   = 1
   min_size   = 1
  }
 
  depends_on = [
   aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
   aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
  ]
 }
```

It creates all the resources but cannot add the worker nodegroup to the eks cluster. does anyone know what is the problem?

```
aws_iam_account_alias.alias: Creation complete after 0s [id=aminbaa]
aws_iam_role.eks-iam-role: Creation complete after 0s [id=eks-iam-role]
aws_iam_role.eks-workernodes-iam-role: Creation complete after 0s [id=eks-workernodes-iam-role]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly-EKS: Creation complete after 0s [id=eks-iam-role-20231111115059381300000001]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy: Creation complete after 1s [id=eks-workernodes-iam-role-20231111115059512800000003]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSClusterPolicy: Creation complete after 1s [id=eks-iam-role-20231111115059452500000002]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly: Creation complete after 1s [id=eks-workernodes-iam-role-20231111115059556700000004]
aws_budgets_budget.eks: Creation complete after 1s [id=218169265088:aws-eks]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy: Creation complete after 1s [id=eks-workernodes-iam-role-20231111115059616900000005]
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds: Creation complete after 1s [id=eks-workernodes-iam-role-20231111115059660100000006]
aws_vpc.main: Creation complete after 1s [id=vpc-0efba82ca7a4ae813]
aws_internet_gateway.gw: Creation complete after 1s [id=igw-05440653f44ed7e5f]
aws_subnet.public_subnets[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-06d7bbbc77f59954f]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-09592afd45f49ca61]
aws_subnet.public_subnets[1]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-031827712d9765202]
aws_subnet.public_subnets[2]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-0e1a424a7f656c6ba]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[1]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-0a386d8d241420598]
aws_subnet.private_subnets[2]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-0626a52464d4ed26e]
aws_route_table.second_rt: Creation complete after 0s [id=rtb-09d079b731f773ccb]
aws_route_table_association.public_subnet_asso[1]: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtbassoc-0faa40c0eadfedbd2]
aws_route_table_association.public_subnet_asso[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtbassoc-0b416eecd9c95200a]
aws_route_table_association.public_subnet_asso[2]: Creation complete after 1s [id=rtbassoc-083007a4aea0f99a2]
aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster: Creation complete after 7m11s [id=eks-cluster]
aws_eks_node_group.worker-node-group: Creating...
        
aws_eks_node_group.worker-node-group: Still creating... [23m40s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: waiting for EKS Node Group (eks-cluster:workernodes) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
│       * i-089cdb74d5bd0b72d: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
│
│
│
│   with aws_eks_node_group.worker-node-group,
│   on main.tf line 169, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group":
│  169: resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group" {
```

Comment: Have you tried to launch an EC2 instance in a private subnet and check internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

- As it exists in the private subnet, verify connectivity with the NAT gateway and ensure the NAT gateway can access the internet
- Nodes can encounter challenges joining the cluster when there is a security group mismatch, preventing communication with the EKS control plane and resulting in timeouts

Comment: thank you for your help. I am very beginner in both terraform and aws. can you please advise why it should be connected to the NAT gateway? why nat gateway should be connected to the internet? and how to verify the connectivity?

Comment: FYI, in the aws console, it is showing these two messages: `NodeCreationFailure` and `Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster`

Comment: FYI, the ec2 instance is in the security group of `sg-02a3cf1cbb71d21fe (eks-cluster-sg-eks-cluster-365256518)`

Comment: ec2 instance is in the same vpc as well resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

Comment: eks cluster is also in the same security group eks-cluster-sg-eks-cluster-365256518

Comment: Read this: https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/networking/subnets/